# my c++ program crashes when receiving user input

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, crash

I am trying to make a program that gets students' names, numbers and subject codes from user. however, when it gets to getting subject codes (which is supposed to be an array of strings), the program crashes. what am i doing wrong here?

```
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct Student {
    string student_number;
    string student_name;
    string* student_codes;

}Student;

void GetStudent(Student* student) {
    int num;
    int numOfSubjects;
    cout<<"enter the number of students:\n";
    cin >> num;
    student = (Student*)malloc(num * sizeof(Student));
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        cout<< "enter student "<<i+1<< "'s name\n";
        cin >> student[i].student_name;
        cout<< "enter student "<<i+1<< "'s number\n";
        cin >> student[i].student_number;
        cout<< "enter the number of subjects:\n";
        cin >> numOfSubjects;
        student->student_codes = (string*)malloc(numOfSubjects * 
sizeof(string));
        for (int j = 0; j < numOfSubjects; j++) {
            cout<< "enter sunject "<<j+1<< "'s code\n";
            cin >> student[i].student_codes[j];
        }

    }
}


int main()
{
    Student student;
    GetStudent(&student);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you shouldnt be using `malloc` and very much related to that you should be aware that c and c++ are two different languages

Comment: Make your life easier and use `std::vector<std::string> student_codes;`.